# How does virtual and physical memory affect cache structure?

Tags: computer-architecture

Working with a question that states:

> Consider a hypothetical machine in which physical address space is
> of 512 words and virtual address space is of 2048 words. The page
> size is 8 words. What is number of bits used for: Page offset,
> Physical Page Number, Virtual Page Number

Since my course uses MIPS, I'm assuming the word size is 4 bytes, so to determine the byte size of each I multiply them by 4 and get: 32, 2048, 8192 respectively.

The total amount of bits used to represent page offset is just those numbers log base 2 so I get 32 bytes which is 5 bits.

I used those 5 bits to determine the page number for physical and virtual memory

> physical memory = 2048 = 11 bits - 5 bits = 6 bits
>
> virtual memory = 8192 = 13 bits - 5 bits = 8 bits

I double-checked those by dividing the words in each space by the words in page size and then logging b2 that number as well and it checked out. Does my logic make sense, does this actually double check my work? Is page offset simply the bits needed to represent page size?

> Now, let’s assume the cache size is 128 words in total. Directly
> mapped with block size of 2 words(8) each. What is the number of
> blocks, sets, and ways for the cache?

I immediately knew it was only 1 way because it was a direct mapped cache.
I determined that there were 64 blocks because there were two words per block and 128 words total so simply 128 / 2.
Since it's directly mapped, I assumed there were 64 sets, one to go with each block.

> If cache access and translation need to be done in parallel
> How many bits of virtual address are used for byte offset? Which bits?
>
> How many bits of virtual address are used for block offset? Which bits?
>
> How many bits of virtual address are used for index? Which bits?

I assumed 2 byte offsets(at least) for the virtual address because I know that's a given. Why is that a given?

For block offset I said 1 bit because there are two words per block and the offset is needed to represent them both in the same space.

For index I took my number of sets and found the bits needed to represent it (log base 2 64) and found 6.

Are there any flaws in my logic? Could anyone explain where I went wrong?

I'm confused about what I should be taking into consideration from the first half of the problem for the latter half. How are pages with the physical 6 bits stored when the index is larger than the entire address? How do the two problems relate to each other at all?

Comment: Where do *byte*s rear there ugly heads?